# Do CVs need their own tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Currently we have [resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume) (very common) and [cv](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cv) (less common). The tag wiki for resume refers to CVs directly, but the CV tag is used specifically for CVs.

Do these need to be separate tags or should they be synonymized? I'm of the opinion that they should be separate and the resume tag wiki should no longer refer to CVs.

Comment: `I'm of the opinion that they should be separate and the resume tag wiki should no longer refer to CVs.` Why?

Comment: @YannisRizos CVs are generally rarer and more specific; a lot more detailed. We already have a *lot* of resume questions, so I don't think splitting tags would be detrimental to either.

Comment: So if a question applies to resumes *or* to CVs, should we just tag it with both? (most likely, the question asker will use one or the other, so users familiar with both tags would need to keep their eyes out to add the other tag).

Comment: @Rarity `CVs are generally rarer and more specific` Resume only applies to the US, my CV _is_ a resume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went and approved a synonym request; CV and Resume tagged questions will now show up as [resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume) on questions.

I went with Resume as the master tag since Resume was the more common usage on questions and in the US, the only place I know of where the distinction is relevant, CVs are much more rare and elaborate; it makes sense to keep the most common semantic usage IMO.

We can always undo this later too.

Answer (score 5):

From the [top voted answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695/48) on ["What exactly is a 'CV'?"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2692/48):

> In most contexts, CV ( Curriculum vitae ) and resume are used interchangeably. Different countries and different industries tend to prefer one term over another. An academic job in any country will typically ask for a CV, a non-academic job in the United States will typically ask for a resume, other countries (such as most European companies) will prefer the term CV. In most cases, everyone is talking about the same thing.

I haven't found a [resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume) question insofar that specifically asks about resumes instead of CVs (haven't looked that hard though), I think they are used interchangeably and we should make them synonyms. And although it might go against the tags' question count, I'd propose CV as the master tag, as it's the most recognizable term of the two (worldwide).

Comment: [This article](http://jobsearch.about.com/cs/curriculumvitae/f/cvresume.htm) suggests that they are different - a CV is longer and more detailed.  Is our answer wrong?

Comment: @NickC Strictly speaking they are different, but their differences are very subtle, and only apply to the US use of the terms, in Europe and probably everywhere else the terms are interchangeable, with CV being the popular term - for example [Europass](http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/en/home), the semi-official CV for the EU, advertises the document as CV, without any mention of the term resume. As the answer states: "In _most_ contexts, CV ( Curriculum vitae ) and resume are used interchangeably...".

Comment: From the standpoint of being proactively lazy, I like going with the popular use on this one.  I"m concerned that the differences are too subtle, and that we'll spend forever retagging posts that aren't tagged right.  If our purpose is to help streamline how people focus on questions, it might be fair to say the people interested in resumes are also interested in CVs.

Comment: @bethlakshmi sounds reasonable to me

Answer (score 2):

My usual rule of thumb for tags is their role as interesting/ignored and I just can't see how someone would be interested in one but not the other, or want to ignore one but not the other. If we make them synonyms, someone searching for one will find both. I think there are some subtle differences (I occasionally write up an academic CV for myself that's very different from my resume) but not worthy of a separate tag.