# Why are resume and cv different tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do CVs need their own tag?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367/do-cvs-need-their-own-tag)

I just spotted a question on the front page with both the resume and cv tag. Surely these should be synonyms? Their wikis even each include the other word.

Comment: See also: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/367/do-cvs-need-their-own-tag

Comment: Kate, I've closed this question as a duplicate of the other; but I don't know if we'd consider the issue closed, so if you'd like, add your voice to the other question.  Thanks!